# Is there a shortcut or command to start a thread in Slack

Tags: slack

Is there a shortcut or a command in Slack I can use to start a thread on the last message?

It's annoying to always grab the mouse between using the keyboard to navigate to the chat and typing the message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use:

1. <kbd>F6</kbd> (Move focus to the next section) or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> (Move focus to the previous section)
2. <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd> to navigate through messages.
3. <kbd>Right</kbd> or <kbd>T</kbd> (Open or reply to a thread)

See [Slack official documentation Slack keyboard shortcuts\Take an action on a message](https://slack.com/intl/en-ua/help/articles/201374536-Slack-keyboard-shortcuts#take-an-action-on-a-message/).

Comment: on the latest release, you can just use `Up` without Step 1. at least in Mac

Answer (score 9):

There is not a single-key way to do this, but it *is* possible to start a thread using only the keyboard:

- Hit Shift-F6 ("move focus to the previous section") to select the message. (Assuming that you have just sent that message. Otherwise you may need a different shortcut.)
- Hit Tab four times to move the focus to "Start a thread".
- Hit Enter.

Boom!

(My original source was https://twitter.com/slackhq/status/918175567740047360?lang=en)

Comment: For the Mac app this approach seems to work, however it's `shift-F6` followed by `shift-tab` six times, then `enter`.

Comment: https://slack.com/help/articles/115003340723-Keyboard-accessibility-in-Slack-#windows-linux-2

Answer (score 7):

At least for me, typically I want to start a thread on the latest message in that channel. Then it's simply <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>T</kbd>.

Comment: This is the best solution and covers my question perfectly. This from my point of view is the correct answer. (but a comment above suggests this shortcut wasn't available back then)

Comment: This is the simplest solution as of 2020.

Answer (score 2):

Small update for Slack version "Production 4.0.0 64-bit":

1. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> (this might be optional if you are already in Message box)
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> (4 times)
3. <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: This is the only currently-working answer for Slack in the browser. I used steps 2 and 3 in the message box.

Answer (score 1):

When you've navigated to the message in your case, you can just press <kbd>T</kbd> instead of 4 times <kbd>Tab</kbd>.